# jdbc connectivity error

Tags: java, jdbc

while establishing database connectivity with java application,i tried to run .jar file it showing an error msg "Failed to load main class manifest attribute from  `c:\program files\sqljdbc_2.0.1803.100_enu\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar` " how i can proceed further?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858782/database-connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run the .jar file. It's a library. Instead you need to reference it whilst running your class file e.g.

```
java -cp c:\program files\..\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar {yourclassfile}
```

You *can* run a .jar file if it's configured as such. However a JDBC .jar won't have the appropriate configuration and you should think of it as similar to a (say) .DLL.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap the path in quotes. There's a space in it.

Answer (score 1):

First [pick one from here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jdbc+tutorial&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_enBG314BG344&ie=UTF-8&aq=0&oq=JDBC+tu)

The .jar file with the driver is not supposed to be run - it is supposed to provide low-level implementation of the communication between your java application and the database in question.

Anyway, what are you doing "while establishing db connectivity" ?